# Take user input and store to array in a file

Tags: java, class, methods, fileoutputstream, bufferedinputstream

I am trying to store multiple user inputs as a byte based file and then take the files numbers and use them for calculation in the program I have written. I started by converting the string to a double, but the I ran into the issue of reading the values and subbing in the the calc methods.  I figured out  that I am suppose to use fileOutputStream but have no idea how to incorporate into the code. Any guidance would be appreciated. Please see code for reference:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class BankApp {
    public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException{

        double cash = 0;
        int years = 0;
        double pv = 0;
        String line = null;

        String filename = "bank.txt";

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("How much money would you like to have?");
        cash = in.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("How many years is your investment?");
        years = in.nextInt();

        Bank1 bank1 = new Bank1(cash, years);

        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename));       
        bw.write(String.valueOf(cash));
        bw.close();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));       
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            //System.out.println(line);
        }

        System.out.println("The present value to invest over the years to reach goal: $"+bank1.presentValue());
        System.out.println("The furture value in the account will be: $"+bank1.futureValue());
    }
}
```

Here is the second class that does all the calculations.

```
public class Bank1 {

    private double cash;
    private double rate = .0425;
    private int years;

    public Bank1(double cash, int years){
        this.cash = cash;
        this.years = years;     
    }n

    public double presentValue(){
        double pv = cash/Math.pow((1+rate), years);
        double present = Math.round(pv *100);
        present = present/100;
        return present;
    }


    public double  futureValue(){
        double fv = this.presentValue()*Math.pow((1+rate), years);
        double future = Math.round(fv *100);
        future = future/100;
        return future;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please consider using [BigDecimals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) instead of `double`s for the calculations to avoid inevitable rounding errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option is to read up on the different types of Character / Byte streams in the java documentation, I usually go there every time I read/write data to find one that suits my need.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/package-summary.html

(This is the documentation for the java.io package in your code you say `import java.io.*` that gives you access to anything listed in the documentation)

When you say "I figured out that I am suppose to use fileOutputStream but have no idea how to incorporate into the code." you don't HAVE to unless this a assignment that requires it, I would use a FileWriter or ObjectOutputStream.  ObjectOutputStream would be perfect for what you are trying to do.

Comment: You could use `ObjectOutputStream.writeLong()` to write your data and `ObjecInputStream.readLong()` to read it.

Comment: Thank you, the assignment just asked me to convert my existing code to byte based. I read that FileOutputStream does this and I am looking OjectOutputStream. Do I still need to write ObjectOutputStream as an array to call the different values?

Comment: In java there are Character Streams and Byte Streams.  Character Streams write only in ASCII characters (ie. instead of writing the number fifty in binary it writes '5' and '0').  Byte Streams write in bytes (8 bits), in a case where it writes a letter it writes in ASCII a ` ` becomes 32 in binary but the number 50 becomes 50 in binary.

Comment: Hay - just wondering, no pressure, if you could mark my answer as the solution if it helped.  Thanks, Harry S.

Comment: There ya go sorry about that

Comment: no problem i am just trying to reach 50 reputation so i can comment